# Get return of async task

Tags: java, android

I have a class that request online json. Is works fine, but the function is void, I need the function return true or false to the activity. This is the example:

```
public class Async extends AbstractService{
  public void getData(fina Context context){
    JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
    try {
        param.put("field_1",   "1");
        param.put("field_3",  "2");
        param.put("field_3", "3");

    }catch (Exception e) {}


    requester = new HttpRequestController().sendPost("auth/device", param, new HttpRequestController.CallBackRequest(){
        @Override
        public void run(final String result) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                     if(resultObj.optBoolean("success")) {
                       //here return true or false
                     }
                }
            }).start();

            System.out.println("test auth 1: " + result);
        }
    });
  }
}

public class MainActivity extends baseActivity{
 ....
     protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     Async auth = new Async();
     auth.getUserDevice(this); //how to test is true or false ?
   }
```

}

Comment: https://imgflip.com/i/29tiii

Answer (score 1):

The function is `void` for a reason. Async functions are not supposed to return something because of their asynchronous nature. It is not possibile to rely on something that you don't know when (or even if) will return something.

If you are interested to do something in case of successful completion of the async task, which I guess it is the case, you should exactly do that. This is an active action that begins exactly inside the block of code where you know that the operation has completed. This action can be resetting a state, or emitting an event to inform whoever is interested of such event.

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask like this:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Boolean,Boolean> {
    JSONObject param;
    MyTask(){
        param = new JSONObject();
        try {
            param.put("field_1",   "1");
            param.put("field_3",  "2");
            param.put("field_3", "3");

        }catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            // do your request call and get result then,

             return resultObj.optBoolean("success");
    }
}
```

then execute like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends baseActivity {
      ....

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        boolean b = new MyTask().execute().get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Now I understand. Tks

Answer (score 0):

change the void to a Boolean, and within the function you can verify that if there is a json is indeed sent somewhere or produced, put a conditional:
if(json.length() > 0) 
return true;